# Error in date picker "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to use the date time picker like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that the I got error in JS undefiend is not a function

Im using bootstrap3 in MVC5 application what can be the issue here ?

I try to add the following librarys which doesnt help...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Include jQuery file before jQuery UI.

Comment: @ShaunakD-can you please tell me which exactly files I need to include ,what is mandatory ...,I little bit confused

Comment: In your code, you're referencing jquery-ui _before_ jquery. jQuery-UI _depends_ on jQuery...so you need to reference jQuery _before_ jQuery-UI.

Comment: Works for me here **http://jsfiddle.net/6byxa/** after changing order of including files. Check whether you are correctly loading the scripts before your JS code.

Comment: @ShaunakD-Thanks now I've just the following references and still it I got the error,any idea?<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call jQUery  top off the all script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: If that didnt help, please do yourself a favor and create a plunkr or jsbin so we can see the problem happening and try to help you from there.

Comment: Are sure jQuery calling success or not @Holger Tans

Comment: @ShibinRagh-what do you mean by success?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your Datepicker instantiate script below HTML code?

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker4" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I tried it out but witout success,do you have any other idea ,or maybe you can tell me which library I must to put...

Comment: The only change I made was change the order of these two script inclusions:
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont have this file inside my script folder ,how should I refer to it in diffrent way...

Comment: Download this plugin to your script folder.

Comment: from where should I do that ?

Comment: this is not jquery this is jQuery-UI different from jQuery

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was problem with jquery-s involved, i need jquery for my layout, and i was importing that part after

```
 @RenderBody()
```

I fixed this by creating in BundleConfig script only for jquery and imported that script before RenderBody() part, of course in my Layout part.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerym").Include(
                "~/Scripts/libs/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

After this, i didnt have problem that jquery is not ready, and i didnt have to import that part on page where i show datetimepicker. This is different datetimepicker from yours but it's basically same:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
    </script>
```